# Selecting cases based on values in previous rows

Tags: spss

I have a binominal value in SPSS called "emotion" that contains "91" and "95". I would like to select all cases that come after twice "95" and are encoded with "91" themselves. Does anybody know a synthax that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your data is sorted in the relevant order, then run this:

```
compute selectthis=(yourvar=91 and lag(yourvar)=95 and lag(yourvar,2)=95).
exe.
select if selectthis=1.
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran this but then SPSS just changed every "95" to "91" so now i just got "91" in my list...

Comment: Please check, before running the `select`, if the right cases were marked with `1` in the new `selectthis` variable. In any case, the condition you described says that you want to select cases that "are encoded with '91' themselves" - so the result can only contain cases coded with `91`.